# How to remove empty rows from the SpreadsheetDocument

Tags: c#, openxml, spreadsheet

How to skip the empty rows from this sheet data?

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file, false))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
                var relationshipId = sheets.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name.Value.ToLower() == SheetName.ToLower()).Id.Value;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
                Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
                SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
                IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();
}
```

Comment: You question and your title are different, you want to skip or want to remove? First thing you need to do is to try and get stuck and ask of help. google that am sure you will find tons of code samples.

Comment: try this: `List<Row> rows = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(row => row.Elements<Cell>().Any(cell => cell.DataType != null)).ToList();`. It will save all non-empty rows so you don't have to worry about finding the "empty" rows.